# how to parse XML document?

Tags: java, xml

I have xml document in variable (not in file). How can i get data storaged in that? I don't have any additional file with that, i have it 'inside' my sourcecode. When i use

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(XML);
```

(XML is my xml variable), i get an error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\netbeans\app-s7013\<network ip_addr="10.0.0.0\8" save_ip="true"> File not found.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read your XML into a StringReader, wrap it in an InputSource, and pass that to your DocumentBuilder:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that XML is a String, don't be confused by the version that takes a string - the string is a URL, not your input!

What you need is the version that takes an input stream.

You need to create an input stream based on a string (I'll try and find code sample, but you can Google for that). Usually a [StringReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) is involved.