# Use Spring/Tomcat's Libs to Parse an XML

Tags: xml, spring, jsp, tomcat, xml-parsing

I'm no developer and picking up things adhoc, but have a little problem. The app I am doing is simple. I make a webservice call to Hyperic to get the status of a group of servers which results in an xml output.

e.g.

```
<LastMetricsDataResponse>
    <Status>Success</Status>
    <LastMetricData resourceId="11678" resourceName="ptseelm-ax4066.myco.com HQ Agent 5.7.1" metricId="15126" metricName="JVM Free Memory">
        <DataPoint timestamp="1380197100000" value="1.479712E7"/>
    </LastMetricData>
    <LastMetricData resourceId="11678" resourceName="ptseelm-ax4066.myco.com HQ Agent 5.7.1" metricId="15127" metricName="JVM Total Memory">
        <DataPoint timestamp="1380197100000" value="3.5864576E7"/>
    </LastMetricData>
</LastMetricsDataResponse>
```

Seeing as the server I am writing the JSP on is a Tomcat6 server with the spring framework libs already there, it seems daft to use any other libs if i dont need to.

All I basically need to do is get perhaps resourceNames, metricNames, timestamp and value... print them in a table or some kind of traffic light thing based on the values.

Its step one I am stuck on, a simple JSP that can simply call the webserviceurl and parse the XML for the things I want into a hashmap or collection or something similar.

Help the noob please :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse XML document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050036/how-to-parse-xml-document)

Comment: -1 There are tons of articles how to parse XML in Java

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a Spring MVC application, I think that the simplest solution is to *marshal* the XML webservice response into a Java Object using simple **JAXB** annotations.

*(JAXB  is not included in Tomcat or Spring, but is a light Jar and solve your problem elegantly)*

Then, from a Spring controller you can put the marhalled object in the **ModelMap** to retrieve the values from your JSP.

- See [this simple tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)  for a basic exemple of JAXB to convert XML to Java POJO and viceversa.
- See [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/)  to understand how pass objects from Spring controllers to JSP

---

But, if your top priority is to use **only** already available libraries, then you can use the Java standard [DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) to parse XML into a [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) and get tag by name as a [NodeList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) collection:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
NodeList lastMetrics = doc.getElementsByTagName("LastMetricData");
```

Comment: Yes I read about JAXB, the point being to use only the libraries already available. We are not talking heavy duty XLST here... some v quick and v dirty for a very small amount of data. No need to complicate the install instructions for co-workers who may need to recreate in the future as it were.

Comment: I edited my answer, please post some of your attempts and some code to bettere help you. Good Luck.

Comment: thanks @zerologiko - big issues to sort in production today, but will attempt something over/after the weekend